# Windows Azure and Blob PHP sample

Tags: php, deployment, azure

I deployed a small php program to windows azure which works fine (it connects to sql azure and add/modify/delete rows)

But now I want to try its blob service.

I searched some samples and I found these:

https://github.com/Interop-Bridges/Windows-Azure-Sample-Kit-4-PHP/tree/master/GuestBookUsingBlobs
https://github.com/Interop-Bridges/Windows-Azure-Sample-Kit-4-PHP/tree/master/GuestBookUsingBlobsTables

I did the necessary modifications (add storage account and key) but after I deployed it into Azure I get "500 - Internal server error. There is a problem with the resource you are looking for, and it cannot be displayed".

what should I do that the sample work correctly?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Check out this tutorial on the Azure PHP website. It is a decently in-depth article on using blob storage.

http://azurephp.interoperabilitybridges.com/articles/tutorial-using-blob-storage

Comment: hi! I tried to you offer but I get the same error. The code in the index.php (no more files) is the following: `<?php
$blob = new Microsoft_WindowsAzure_Storage_Blob(
    'blob.core.windows.net',
    'storage_accountname',
    'account_key'
);

$blob->createContainerIfNotExists('kepek');

$blob->listBlobs('kepek');

?>`

Comment: Hrm, there must be an error being thrown somewhere. Turn on error_reporting and display_errors and see if anything shows up. If you other PHP files run fine this one should too